# How to fix localhost:8000 prompt login after i submit the authentication using Vue Js And Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I have problem regarding on my authentication after I login there is prompt localhost:8000 login or Sign in, this is the first time I encounter this, I don't know what this called, i don't find any reference for this. currently I am using laravel for the backend and vue js for front end. so this project created by old developer. so now I need to revise some module on there project, however i Login on the system in shows this prompt. note that this project is currently working and there is no error and prompt login when I login.

Here is prompt sign shown after I login.

Configuration:

1. Laravel Passport
2. Vuex For State Management
3. Vue Js

[image: Prompt Message]

**METHOD:**

```
methods:{
        authenticate(){
            this.login_alert = false
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result)=>{
                if(result){
                    const self = this;
                    const authUser = {}
                    try{
                        const data = {
                            username: this.email,
                            password: this.password,
                            remember: this.remember_me,
                            client_id: '2',
                            client_secret: 'just secret only',
                            grant_type : 'password',
                            scope : ''
                        }
                        this.$store.dispatch('AUTH_REQUEST',data)
                            .then(response=>{
                                authUser.access_token = response.access_token
                                authUser.refresh_token = response.refresh_token
                                authUser.expires_in = response.expires_in
                                window.localStorage.setItem('project_token',JSON.stringify(authUser))

                                /*LOGIN*/
                                this.login_alert = false
                                this.loading = false

                                window.location.reload()
                            })
                            .catch(error=>{
                                this.login_alert = true
                                window.localStorage.removeItem('project_token')
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    }catch(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            })
        
        }
    },
```

**AUTH REQUEST:**

```
AUTH_REQUEST:({commit,dispatch},obj)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        axios({
                url: '/oauth/token',
                data: obj,
                method:'post',
                config:'JSON'
            })
            .then(response=>{
                if(response.status == 200){
                    resolve(response.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                reject(error);
                localStorage.removeItem('project_token');
                commit('AUTH_ERROR',error);
            })
    
    })
},
```

Hope someone can help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're requesting something that is behind [HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Nothing in your question shows what this resource might be or where that's been configured though so you won't get much help here until you add more details

Comment: sorry for that. this is the first time i used this language. i just chop each code. yah basically the old developer use vuex for state management and laravel passport use for token